# How to make images scroll from center to left in HTML?

Tags: html

I have been wondering how to make images **scroll from center to left**, like how this image does in this site.
http://www.kiminona.com/index.html#story

I've tried using `<marquee>` tag, but all I could do is for it to scroll from right to left. And as I search for how, all I found is ways to do it in CSS. I need to know how in **HTML-only**.

Comment: Why can you not use CSS?

Comment: You can't do it in HTML only. `<marquee>` is a leftover for decades ago, in a perfect world even that wouldn't exist at all.

Comment: Yes, I myself had wanted to use CSS so bad... however, my teacher only allows us to use HTML. Oh well, if it is so..

Comment: No marquee. Look for a decent scroller plugin written in JS.

Answer (score 0):

you still can use **the old marquee** in this case. to loop it from **center** to **left**, the trict is to put marquee inside the left **div** like below

```css
.item {
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 300px;
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image" class="item">
<marquee>This text will scroll from _center_ to left</marquee>
</div>
<div id="content" class="item">
content
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you not to use the marquee tag as it is deprecated by w3c, but, if you have to and can only use HTML then you can use the direction attribute in the tag. You can create a div and style if for half the page width and then apply the marquee tag within it.

```
<marquee direction="left">Image Goes Here</marquee>
```

If you are able to use CSS then you can use keyframes. There is some good information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) on how to use them.